Flexbox container wont take the entire width and height on my page
Hello everyone im trying to create an html page with a header, main, footer layout. Every element is inside a flexbox column container. The problem is that when im viewing the page with mobile toolbar on chrome set to an iphone 14 pro max the page looks like the photo bellow:



@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #8a1313;
}

img {
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-links ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 30px;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.navbar-links li a:hover {
  color: #8a1313;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-offset: 7px;
}

.main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.6.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Kc323vGBEqzTmouAECnVceyQqyqdsSiqLQISBL29aUW4U/M7pSPA/gEUZQqv1cwx4OnYxTxve5UMg5GT6L4JJg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="flex-container">
  <header class="header">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="header-logo">
        <img src="Symposium Radio LOGO White.png" alt="Logo">
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Αρχική</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Σχετικά</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Η ομάδα μας</a></li>
          <!-- <li><a href="#">Πρόγραμμα</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Επικοινωνία</a></li> -->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main class="main">Main</main>

  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>



How can i fix this issue?

There's not enough horizontal space for all these navbar menu items. note that these sit in a ul with display:flex and no wrapping. you would have to apply different styling to the menu to allow it to fit within the horizontal space. Like applying flex-wrap:wrap or flex-direction:column on the ul, or word-break:break-all on the li items.
